# Adding a parameter with http in the url doesn't let me to get the parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using an external web service and it uses an Iframe to show my page.
When it shows my page it appends to it it's parameters:

```
?assignmentId=asda&hitId=asda&workerId=asda&turkSubmitTo=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com
```

I want to get the assignmentId parameter, but it doesn't work. What I know is that removing the https in the params will make it work. What should I do and why does that happen?

I am using PHP5 with Zend Framework.

Comment: You can probably rely on the `$_GET` super variable instead of the Zend Framework request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it just as you would normally access the parameter.

The only reason you shouldn't be able to is if you have setParamSource to only use 'POST'.

So try again using `$this->getRequest()->getParam('assignmentId');`

Also, if all that fails, just directly access `$_GET['assignmentId']`.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$assignmentId = $this->_getParam('assignmentId');
```

in this way is if the parameter arrives by post or via get the withdraw more! ;)